# get 5 records based on lastModifiedDate

Tags: developer-console

I have 20 records in Account whose Name is "sahitya" and I want to get 5 records based on `LastModifiedDate`.

```
[SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name = 'sahitya' LIMIT 5];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple, I'm assuming your current Query is:

```
[SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name = 'sahitya' LIMIT 5];
```

Just as you're filtering by `Name` you'd just need to filter by `LastModifiedDate` which is a `DateTime` field.

To do this, you'd need to at least one `DateTime` variable.

For instance, you can set a `DateTime` using the following Apex Method:

```
Datetime.newInstance(Integer year, Integer month, Integer day, Integer hour, Integer minute, Integer second);
```

Or, in practise:

```
Datetime first = Datetime.newInstance(2016, 12, 13, 00, 00, 00);
```

That will return a `DateTime` that is hard-coded to be "at midnight today". If you wanted it to be a bit more dynamic:

```
Datetime second = System.now();
```

This will return the `DateTime` as of right now.

So, if we wanted to query records that are greater than midnight as of today, but less than right now, you'd just enter the following query:

```
[SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name = 'sahitya' AND LastModifiedDate > :first AND LastModifiedDate < :second LIMIT 5];
```

Comment: OP could also see if any of the [SOQL date literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) would work.